# Use swift static library in Unity iOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to integrate my Unity game with the iOS static library that I found on Github. The library is in Swift, however, I forked the library and I provided objective-c bindings necessary to make a call from C# code.

My static library is available in my xCode project under the products tab. To use it in Unity I copy-pasted generated library from the directory available under "Reveal in file explorer" to Unity. I put my library in the Plugin directories.

When I run my game on iOS simulator via generated by Unity solution I'm getting an error:

```
2020-11-02 13:56:43.450062+0100 NewUnityProject[4357:59213] Error loading /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D7307D5-D320-4AEB-A0DE-581C61CB3E14/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1C4440FF-C7C6-486B-ADC8-F8A794A83CD9/NewUnityProject.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework: dlopen(/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D7307D5-D320-4AEB-A0DE-581C61CB3E14/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1C4440FF-C7C6-486B-ADC8-F8A794A83CD9/NewUnityProject.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework, 265): Symbol not found: _$s10Foundation3URLVMn
 Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cwkdvrbwlxwbfzbpzacumxcttcmy/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphonesimulator/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework
 Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cwkdvrbwlxwbfzbpzacumxcttcmy/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphonesimulator/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework
2020-11-02 13:56:43.473282+0100 NewUnityProject[4357:59213] Error loading /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D7307D5-D320-4AEB-A0DE-581C61CB3E14/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1C4440FF-C7C6-486B-ADC8-F8A794A83CD9/NewUnityProject.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework: dlopen(/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D7307D5-D320-4AEB-A0DE-581C61CB3E14/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1C4440FF-C7C6-486B-ADC8-F8A794A83CD9/NewUnityProject.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework, 265): Symbol not found: _$s10Foundation3URLVMn
 Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cwkdvrbwlxwbfzbpzacumxcttcmy/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphonesimulator/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework
 Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cwkdvrbwlxwbfzbpzacumxcttcmy/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphonesimulator/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework
```

To validate Unity support step by step I've created an objective-c static library - Untiy was able to make a call to library and I didn't get an error. After that I added swift support to my objective-c library and then I got once again a problem with flat namespace:

```
2020-11-02 13:37:12.848568+0100 NewUnityProject[3034:44789] Error loading /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D7307D5-D320-4AEB-A0DE-581C61CB3E14/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4E2199BA-7743-484E-AD01-636C4296BE85/NewUnityProject.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework: dlopen(/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D7307D5-D320-4AEB-A0DE-581C61CB3E14/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4E2199BA-7743-484E-AD01-636C4296BE85/NewUnityProject.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework, 265): Symbol not found: _$sBOWV
 Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cwkdvrbwlxwbfzbpzacumxcttcmy/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphonesimulator/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework
 Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cwkdvrbwlxwbfzbpzacumxcttcmy/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphonesimulator/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework
2020-11-02 13:37:12.874398+0100 NewUnityProject[3034:44789] Error loading /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D7307D5-D320-4AEB-A0DE-581C61CB3E14/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4E2199BA-7743-484E-AD01-636C4296BE85/NewUnityProject.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework: dlopen(/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D7307D5-D320-4AEB-A0DE-581C61CB3E14/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4E2199BA-7743-484E-AD01-636C4296BE85/NewUnityProject.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework, 265): Symbol not found: _$sBOWV
 Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cwkdvrbwlxwbfzbpzacumxcttcmy/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphonesimulator/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework
 Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/use/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cwkdvrbwlxwbfzbpzacumxcttcmy/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphonesimulator/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework
```

I have been trying to set different xCode flags like "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" or "Enable Modules" but still no luck to run my game on iOS simulator.

Any hints are very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running it on a device, just to rule out a simulator issue?

Comment: No, I haven't - however our game work on Simulator without any problem and I think it our goal is to still add support for simulator - our static library is universal library that has support for simulator and device sdk.